# Unable to create new service - Selenium + Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have an error in my Jenkins + Selenium integration, the Selenium Grid Version is 3.7.1 (Installed by default for the Jenkins Selenium Plugin). I'm using the last chromedriver version. When I run my test on Jenkins the I get the following errors:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
System info: host: 'xxxxxxx', ip: 'xxxxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 187 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at com.xxxxxxxx.util.utilities.DriverUtils.configureDriver(DriverUtils.java:47)
    at com.xxxxxxxxx.features.accederSistema.iniciarSesion.CP01IniciarSesion.openNavigatorToLogin(CP01IniciarSesion.java:52)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41608192/631619

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your ChromeDriver path.

For this example code,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D://selenium/chromedriver.exe");
cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
browser = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/hub"),cap);
```

Check and ensure that the chromedriver.exe file is actually available on the said path ("D://selenium/chromedriver.exe") and has executable permission assigned to it.

This whould help resolve your issue.

Comment: You literally answered my question 4 years later haha

Comment: So it worked? If so might be a good idea to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I don't know I'm not a QA analyst anymore lmao